# setting background color of child window using window's handle

Tags: c++, winapi, colors, background

I have defined and created a bunch of child windows in my main window using `handle_to_this_window[i] = CreateWindow(L"EDIT",...)`
type of call.

I now need to create a function that will allow me to set background color of any one of those windows.
Something like:

`R_color_value = 0, G_color_value = 200, B_color_value = 0;`
`ChangeChildBackgroundColor(handle_to_this_window[6], R_color_value, G_color_value, B_color_value);`

`R_color_value = 200, G_color_value = 0, B_color_value = 0;`
`ChangeChildBackgroundColor(handle_to_this_window[7], R_color_value, G_color_value, B_color_value);`

Could anyone point me in the right direction for how to achieve this, please?

Comment: Process the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message for your window(s) and draw the background

Comment: Look into `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`.

Comment: @RichardCritten: For an edit control, have the parent window process the [`WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761691.aspx) message instead. Or switch to a RichEdit control and send it an [`EM_SETBKGNDCOLOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774228.aspx) message

Comment: @RemyLebeau, the OP said child windows, was just trying to help with the question asked.  I know control can be different.

Comment: @RichardCritten: I know the OP said *child* windows. Their *parent* window receives `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` on their behalf: "*An edit control that is not read-only or disabled sends the WM_CTLCOLOREDIT message to its parent window when the control is about to be drawn. By responding to this message, **the parent window can use the specified device context handle to set the text and background colors of the edit control**.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
struct ChildControlInfo
{
    HWND Wnd;
    HBRUSH BkGndBrush;
    COLORREF BkGndColor;
};

ChildControlInfo ChildControls[...];

...

void ChangeChildBackgroundColor(int ChildIndex, COLORREF NewColor)
{
    ChildControlInfo &Child = ChildControls[ChildIndex];
    if ((Child.BkGndColor != NewColor) || (!Child.BkGndBrush))
    {
        if (Child.BkGndBrush) DeleteObject(Child.BkGndBrush);
        Child.BkGndBrush = CreateSolidBrush(NewColor);
        Child.BkGndColor = NewColor;
        if (Child.Wnd) InvalidateRect(Child.Wnd, NULL, TRUE);
    }
}
```

```
// in the parent window procedure...
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
{
    HDC hDc = reinterpret_cast<HDC>(wParam);
    HWND hEdit = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(lParam);

    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(ChildControls); ++i)
    {
        ChildControlInfo &Child = ChildControls[i];
        if (Child.Wnd == hEdit)
        {
            SetBkColor(hDc, Child.BkGndColor);
            return reinterpret_cast<LRESULT>(Child.BkGndBrush);
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

```
memset(&ChildControls[i], 0, sizeof(ChildControlInfo));
ChildControls[i].Wnd = CreateWindow(L"EDIT",...);.
ChangeChildBackgroundColor(i, RGB(...));

...

ChangeChildBackgroundColor(6, RGB(0, 200, 0));
ChangeChildBackgroundColor(7, RGB(200, 0, 0));

...

// during cleanup...
for(int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(ChildControls); ++i)
{
    ChildControlInfo &Child = ChildControls[i];
    DestroyWindow(Child.Wnd);
    DeleteObject(Child.BkGndBrush);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare a brush as global variable:

```
HBRUSH gbrush;
```

Somewhere in your code you have to define the brush. For example in main window procedure:

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
    gbrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(200, 255, 255));
    //...
}
```

Then change the "background color" and "background brush" in `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`:

```
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
{
    HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
    HWND hedit = (HWND)lParam;
    SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(200, 255, 255));
    return (LRESULT)gbrush;
}
```

This will change the background color for all edit controls. You can use the `hedit` value to handle the edit boxes differently.

Comment: Note that this code needs to be implemented in the window procedure of the **parent window**, and in order to implement `ChangeChildBackgroundColor()` in this manner, you would have to keep track of an array of Edit/Color pairs that `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` can look at to know which brush to return based on the specified Edit control. Whenever `ChangeChildBackgroundColor()` is called, store the new color in the array and invalidate the Edit control to trigger a new paint so `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` can return the new color for it.

Comment: And you do not need `SetBkColor()`, the Edit's background gets drawn with the returned brush. That is stated in the documentation: "*If an application processes this message, it must return the handle of a brush. **The system uses the brush to paint the background of the edit control**.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau: It needs `SetBkColor` otherwise text background color jumps back to default Window color when edit control has focus. Then it goes back to custom color when edit control loses focus.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I think I can do array just fine, if I knew how to apply it. I have added some global variables to specify RGB() values. So, now when I want to change background of a specific child, I: set those variables to the color I want, then call InvalidateRect(handle_to_the_child[i], NULL, TRUE); It then uses the code in WM_CTLCOLOREDIT to set the background. But I do need to figure out how to implement this array thing. hEdit would have the handle to my child window when I call InvalidateRect and I somehow need to get the value of that "i" from that. Would I use some kind of hash table?

Comment: @a1s2d3f4: I posted an answer with an example.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Beautiful. Exactly what I needed - thanks!

Comment: @RemyLebeau One more question based on my new experience: is there a way to know _when_ the WM_CTLCOLOREDIT actually processes my call? I am now trying to add a feature where my child windows do a kind of blinking pattern (changing colors multiple times in real time), and so I need to be able to call the ChangeChildBackgroundColor multiple times , but only after I know that the previous call did "go through" and the child did change color. Is it possible with the current approach? (forgive my noobness).

Comment: You don't need to worry about that.  Start a timer to call `ChangeChildBackgroundColor()` when needed. Every color change will invalidate the window.  The OS will consolidate multiple invalidations for you. The window is painted when the OS is ready to paint it (unless you call `UpdateWindow()` or `RedrawWindow()` to force it). The window will issue `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` whenever it is being painted, just return the latest color. Let the timer do the work, the rest is just painting logic.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks - Timer usage and UpdateWindow() combination did the trick.